# how to get previous version id of specific file in S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the bucket name and the file name using JAVA.

How could I want to find the previous version Id (the one version just before the latest version)?

My final goal is to read the file content of that specific version.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`listObjectVersions()`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#listObjectVersions-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> Returns metadata about all versions of the objects in a bucket. You can also use request parameters as selection criteria to return metadata about a subset of all the object versions.

It is similar to listing the bucket, but instead of just returning Objects, it also returns Versions of Objects.

You can specify a `Prefix` to reduce the number of results (eg give it the Key of a specific Object).

You can then use the `VersionId` that is returned inside `GetObject()` to retrieve that specific version.